# I'm connected with OpenConnect, but Network pane says "Not connected" to VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openconnect

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2. I use the Network pane to connect to wireless, then I use one of the VPN options to connect to VPN. At the top of the pane it says

```
         MyCompany VPN
         Not connected
```

I know the VPN is working because I can access my company subnet.
I'm using some kind of OpenConnect plugin with the Network menu, maybe it's sending the wrong status-code to the Network daemon?

Comment: There's this related question

[I have internet access but it says “not connected” to the network I'm on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860758/i-have-internet-access-but-it-says-not-connected-to-the-network-im-on)

where the "Not Connected" status is reported in the pane specific to the given wireless connection. Maybe it has the same root problem.

Comment: When I click to return to the "all settings" pane, and then click back onto the "Network" icon, the refreshed pane now says "connected".
Maybe it's just a matter of having the pane refresh itself when the connection is established. Would this be easy to do?